# Converting numerical column values into bins in python

Tags: python, dataset, data-science, categorical-data, bins

I am a newbie in python programming for data science. I was trying to convert numerical column values into bins with the code below:

```
bins = [12, 24, 48, 60, np.inf]
names = ['Tenure_12', 'Tenure_24', 'Tenure_48', 'Tenure_60']
telco['tenure_bin'] = pd.cut(telco['tenure'], bins, labels=names)
```

I am getting this error:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'.
'telco' is the name of the dataset and 'tenure' is the column name  whose values I am trying to convert into bins

Can I please get some help on how to do away with this error?

Answer (score 0):

For your benifit, I recommend you give a working example. For instance, what's telco?
(This is not a comment only because my rep doesn't allow me)